# issue adding multiple input fields to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following form that contains many rows (the visitor can add new lines by clicking on a button). I would like to add all the entries to an array to send via $.ajax.

This is the form:

```
<li class=aff class=gastosRow>
    <label>Descripción</label>
    <input class=gastosDescrizione type=text size=30>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Importe</label>
    <input class=gastosImporto type=text>
</li>
```

This is the array that should keep all the entries:

```
    var gastosArray = [];

    $('.gastosRow, .aff').map(function(){var row = $(this);

    gastosArray.push({descrizione: row.find('.gastosDescrizione').val(), importo: row.find('.gastosImporto').val()});
});
```

But the result of the array is not the one I wanted. I would like to have for each row `(gastosArray[])`,  a value for `gastosDescrizione`, and a value for `gastosImporto`. It is not working now and listing only the values of `gastosDescrizione`...

Comment: You have given some invalid markups and scripts, Please provide valid code in order to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm using notepad++ and don't have a validator

Comment: but you can still copy/paste valid HTML markup... Now provide the rendered HTML!

Comment: @A. Wolff settle down Bro. The user is trying... no need for rudeness.

Comment: @Phlume i'm sorry, i didn't mean to be rude, it was just an advice, my bad if you think my previous comment was rude

Comment: @Gabz this is not valid: `<li class=aff class=gastosRow>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While seeing your mark up, you are having a text box with the class `gastosImporto` which is present next to your current selection, so try to use `.next()` in your case to achieve what you needed.

Try,

```
<li class='gastosRow aff'>
    <label>Descripción</label>
    <input class=gastosDescrizione type=text size=30>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Importe</label>
    <input class='gastosImporto' type=text>
</li>
```

JS:

```
var gastosArray = [];
$('.gastosRow,.aff').each(function(){
  var row = $(this);
  gastosArray.push({
    descrizione: row.find('.gastosDescrizione').val(),
    importo:     row.next().find('.gastosImporto').val()
  });
});
```

Comment: No need to use `map` if you're not going to use the results or return a value; just use `each`.

Comment: @Phrogz Yes you are right.! you could have edited that too. :)

Comment: it does work correctly, and correct the suggestion to use each() instead of map(). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` and `get`:

```
var gastosArray = $('.gastosRow, .aff').map(function () {
   return {
        descrizione: $(this).find('.gastosDescrizione').val(),
        importo: $(this).find('.gastosImporto').val()
    }
}).get();
```